# unable to start genymotion virtual device and in virtual box

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualbox, genymotion

I'm using Genymotion v2.4 on Windows 8 Pro to create Virtual Device successfully, but when I try to run it I get this error: Unable to start Genymotion Virtual Device.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QO0oQ.png)

Trying to run it via Virtualbox, I got this error message:

- [Screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wzE7N.png)
- [Screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gk75P.png)

Virtual Device previously could run well until I got this issue.

Can someone please tell me how to Fix it?

Comment: Did you try to reinstall VirtualBox on your computer? Is this problem happening with all the devices?

Answer (score 0):

1. If you are using Windows try use compatible
2. Try install Virtual Box and Genymotion